# MongoDB 3.6: How to search by Text Index field when that field is encryted?

Tags: java, mongodb

We have used java encrypted firstName & lastName fields before save to MongoDB collection by GDPR requirement. These 2 fields also applied **text index** to allow the searching.

Problem: we cannot search by text index for firstName and lastName fields

Question: How to solve my issue?

Comment: first encrypt search string then you can perform search operation sorry it was an suggation ignore if was an stupid idea

Comment: Thank for your feedback. But it's not solution for me.